# how to get a key for a given value in terraform

Tags: terraform

My usecase is
I have datacenter list for each region. If I give datacenter as input, I want to get the region. I can create a map like dallas - us-south, wdc - us-south. In such cases, the list will be big. Is there a way to do it effectively in terraform ?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you've tried so far and explain how that doesn't work for your use cases?

Comment: I did not get how to code it as there is no support for conditions
my requirement is 
us-south = {dal, wdc}
eu-gb = {fra, ams}

my input is dal. 
if (input in us-south) then region = us-south
if (input in eu-gb) then region = eu-gb